# Get coordinates of the boundary of a continent

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, geography

I'm trying to obtain the coordinates of the border of the continents. I need this information to be ordered such that when I do, for example,

```
ListLinePlot[data]
```

It does not yield a messed up image, as happens for disordered points. Initially I was trying by highlighting points on images of maps, and the detecting the points. This approach was really problematic. However, I find that Mathematica has a built in functionality which gives me just what I need, but for countries. That is for example,

```
CountryData["Iran", "FullCoordinates"][[1]]
```

I'm exploring if this can be done for continents as entities, and I have found that the information for a continent as a polygon can be obtained as,

```
africa = Entity["GeographicRegion", "Africa"]["Polygon"]
```

Is there any way by which I can obtain a list of points corresponding to the coordinates of this continent?

Answer (score 3):

Although `ListLinePlot` can plot coordinates for geographic data, I recommend that you avoid this method and use `GeoGraphics` instead. Some of the advantages are:

- selecting map features, e.g, islands
- using map projections (with the `GeoProjection` option)
- locating points on the map (using `GeoMarker`)

But first, to answer your question about coordinates, you can get them for the outline of a continent, Africa for example, from its polygon:

```
continentPoly = Entity["GeographicRegion", "Africa"]["Polygon"];
data = continentPoly[[1, 1, 1]];(*a long list of coordinate pairs*)
```

There's other useful information available from `GeoBounds` and `GeoBoundingBox`.

```
GeoBounds[Entity["GeographicRegion", "Africa"]]
(* {{-34.8341, 37.5423}, {-25.36, 57.8092}} *)

GeoBoundingBox[Entity["GeographicRegion","Africa"]]
(* {GeoPosition[{-34.8341, -25.36}], GeoPosition[{37.5423, 57.8092}]} *)
```

**Using GeoGraphics**

Let's look at some of the advantages of using `GeoGraphics`. If you use `ListLinePlot`, you lose ease-of-use capabilities. For example, here's a map of the continent of Africa including the island of Madagascar.

```
GeoGraphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[None],
    Polygon[GeoPosition[continentPoly[[1, 1, {1,2}]]]]},
  GeoBackground -> None, GeoProjection -> "Mercator"]
```

[image: Africa map]

It's simple to choose the orthographic projection instead of Mercator:

```
GeoGraphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[None],
    Polygon[GeoPosition[continentPoly[[1, 1, {1, 2}]]]]},
  GeoBackground -> None, GeoProjection -> "Orthographic"]
```

[image: orthographic projection]

When you want to highlight a point on the map, `GeoMarker` does the work for you.

```
GeoGraphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[Red],
    Polygon[GeoPosition[continentPoly[[1, 1, {1, 2}]]]],
  GeoMarker[Entity["City", {"Pretoria", "Gauteng", "SouthAfrica"}]]},
  GeoBackground -> None, GeoProjection -> "Mercator"]
```

[image: map with a location]

Here's a map of several locations with the orthographic projection.

```
GeoGraphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[Orange],
    Polygon[GeoPosition[continentPoly[[1,1,{1,2}]]]],
  GeoMarker[Entity["City", {"Pretoria", "Gauteng", "SouthAfrica"}]],
  GeoMarker[Entity["GeographicRegion", "Africa"]["HighestFeature"], "Color" -> Green],
  GeoMarker[Entity["GeographicRegion", "Africa"]["CenterCoordinates"], "Color" -> Blue]},
  GeoBackground -> None, GeoProjection -> "Orthographic"]
```

[image: several map locations]

All of these features would be tricky or difficult to implement with `ListLinePlot`.

**An additional feature unique to GeoGraphics**

Another advantage with `GeoGraphics` is that you can use `Get Coordinates` to read positions directly from the graphic in a notebook (see the left-hand image). If you click on a point (the small red point on the right-hand image), you can copy and paste the point's geo-position on the map.

[image: get coordinates from notebook graphic]

```
{GeoPosition[{18.293290236969238`, -1.4117877048275167`}, "ITRF00"]}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you want points from the Mercator projection because you're trying to plot in 2D with `ListLinePlot`? Otherwise you'd be asking for the polygon wrapped on the sphere.

```
(* get the GeoPosition points from the polygon *)
points=Flatten[First@First[Entity["GeographicRegion","Africa"]["Polygon"]],1];

(* convert to Mercator projection and plot *)
ListLinePlot[
  GeoGridPosition[First@Entity["GeographicRegion","Africa"]["Polygon"],"Mercator"][[1]]
, AspectRatio->1]
```

Bear in mind Africa has loads of islands, so if you just want the main continent border then you need to select the first set of points:

```
ListLinePlot[
  GeoGridPosition[
   First@Entity["GeographicRegion","Africa"]["Polygon"],
   "Mercator"][[1,1]]
  , AspectRatio->1, PlotRange->All
]
```

[image]

Comment: The first plot seems to fit a Mercator projection, but the shape of the second plot is "off" somehow. Is longitude stretched, or latitude compressed? Aspect ratio 1.2 seems to help.